# IndexError: list index out of range in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

The error appears on the last line of the code segment below, and i'm not sure why. I'm attempting to learn from a video i found online, which has the same code, even when i've checked multiple times and seems to work fine.

```
class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position=[50,50]
        self.body=[[100,50], [90.50], [80,50]]
        self.direction = "RIGHT"
        self.changeDirectionTo=self.direction

    def getBody(self):
        return self.body

window=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
snake = Snake()

while True:
    for pos in snake.getBody():
        pygame.draw.rect(window, pygame.Color(0,225,0),
                         pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 10,10))
```

Comment: Does this code sample really run? You write `for pos in snake.getBody()`, but snake is never defined. Even if it was `Snake` instead, the class would have to first be initialized into an object, so `Snake()`.

Comment: Sorry, missed from entering that line here. Yes, the object was initialized.

Comment: It's because in the `self.body=[[100,50], [90.50], [80,50]]` you wrote `90.50` instead of `90,50` so the second element is a sublist containing one `float` value, not the two integers the `pygame.draw.rect()` line expects.

Comment: Typos are off-topic, so this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

That second body part has a period instead of comma separating the 90 and the 50, so there is no element at pos[1]. Just replace the period with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You have one float element instead of two integers in your list. Change **[90.50]** to [90, 50].

```
self.body=[[100,50], [90.50], [80,50]]
```